# Forge Design Automation showing deprecated

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-designautomation

Good morning,
I am writing a console app that uses Design Automation and it seems that some of the classes like AppBundlesApi, WorkItemsApi and ActivitiesApi are listed as deprecated.

Is that correct? Should I implement my own version using RestSharp?
[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Please use the package:
https://www.nuget.org/packages/Autodesk.Forge.DesignAutomation

See the update here:
https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/design-automation-v3-net-package

Comment: Thanks for the reply...I have done that already as you can see in my screenshot but still is showing the message

Comment: @CesareCaoduro the Autodesk.Forge package does contain a Design Automation v3 objects, but this package is deprecated in favor of Autodesk.Forge.DesignAutomation package, please use this latest. Sorry about the confusion.

Comment: Thanks @AugustoGoncalves. Only the Design Automation shoulb be updated, the authorization and the OSS apis will still be pointing to the Autodesk.Forge package. Is that right?

Comment: @AugustoGoncalves another quick question. I am using this example https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge-api-dotnet-design.automation by directly creating the API object, it seems working fine when I try to list the app bundles but, how can I push the token with the defined scopes?

Comment: @CesareCaoduro yes, only Design Automation has a separated package. I would suggest checking this sample: https://learnforge.autodesk.io/#/tutorials/modifymodels

Answer (score 0):

You must use the [new package](http://%20https://www.nuget.org/packages/Autodesk.Forge.DesignAutomation). Using the old package will result in this warning. [The article](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/design-automation-v3-net-package) might be confusing because it shows some content from "Original article". This original article predates the new SDK.